# Mule CPU maxing out with a very small load

Tags: mule, cpu-usage, esb

System under test: Mule ESB 3.3.1
OS: CentOS 5.1 64 bit
Quad-core 3 GHz
32 GB RAM

The Mule ESB is simply intercepting SOAP requests; validating the SOAP requests for a valid token and simply forwarding the request to a pre-determined web server hosting the web service.

When we run performance tests using SOAP UI, the CPU maxes to 100% very very quickly at 10 requests per second.

```
<spring:beans>
     <spring:bean class="ca.mpac.soa.BAMNotificationListener" id="BAMNotificationListener"/>
     <context:component-scan base-package="ca.mpac.soa"/>
     <util:properties id="appProps" location="classpath:bedrock.properties"/>
</spring:beans>
<notifications>
    <notification event="COMPONENT-MESSAGE"/> <notification-listener ref="BAMNotificationListener"/>
</notifications>

<context:property-placeholder location="bedrock.properties"/>
<object-to-string-transformer name="SecurityTokenResponseToString" doc:name="Object to String"/>
<custom-transformer name="WSDLTransformer" class="ca.mpac.soa.WSDLTransformer" doc:name="Java"/>

<flow name="bedrock" doc:name="bedrock">
            <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="${proxy.host}" port="${proxy.port}" doc:name="proxy">
                    <not-filter>
                            <wildcard-filter pattern="/favicon.ico" caseSensitive="true"/>
                    </not-filter>
            </http:inbound-endpoint>
    <component class="ca.mpac.soa.HttpAccessLog" doc:name="HttpAccessLog"/>
    <!-- <logger message="#[header:INBOUND:http.version] #[header:INBOUND:http.method] #[header:INBOUND:Host]#[header:INBOUND:http.request.path]?#[header:INBOUND:http.query.string] #[header:INBOUND:MULE_REMOTE_CLIENT_ADDRESS] #[header:INBOUND:User-Agent]" level="INFO" doc:name="Header Information" category="mule.http.accesslog"/> -->
    <!-- logger message="Incoming request: #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Incoming request"/> -->
    <choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when evaluator="groovy" expression="message.getInboundProperty('http.request.path')==~'^/rest/.*'">
            <processor-chain>
                <flow-ref name="REST" doc:name="REST Flow"/>
            </processor-chain>
        </when>
        <when evaluator="groovy" expression="message.getInboundProperty('http.request.path')==~'^/soap/.*'">
            <processor-chain>
                <flow-ref name="SOAP" doc:name="SOAP Flow"/>
            </processor-chain>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <processor-chain>
                <flow-ref name="404NotFound" doc:name="404 Not Found"/>
            </processor-chain>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
</flow>
<sub-flow name="REST" doc:name="REST">
    <!-- logger message="Launching REST Flow: #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Launching REST Flow"/> -->
    <choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when evaluator="groovy" expression="message.getInboundProperty('http.request.path')==~'^/rest/security/gettoken$'">
            <processor-chain>
                <choice doc:name="Choice">
                    <when evaluator="header" expression="INBOUND:http.method=POST">
                        <processor-chain>
                            <mulexml:xml-to-object-transformer returnClass="ca.mpac.soa.ClientAuthenticationRequest" doc:name="XML to Object">
                                <mulexml:alias name="credential" class="ca.mpac.soa.ClientAuthenticationRequest"/>
                            </mulexml:xml-to-object-transformer>
                            <!-- logger message="Accessing to ${openam.host}:${openam.port}/openam/identity/authenticate?username=#[payload.username]&amp;password=#[payload.password]&amp;uri=realm=${openam.realm}" level="INFO" doc:name="Accessing to URL"/> -->
                            <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="${openam.host}" port="${openam.port}" path="openam/identity/authenticate?username=#[payload.username]&amp;password=#[payload.password]&amp;uri=realm=${openam.realm}" method="GET" responseTransformer-refs="SecurityTokenResponseToString" doc:name="OpenAM Get Token"/>
                            <choice doc:name="Choice">
                                <when evaluator="header" expression="INBOUND:http.status=200">
                                    <processor-chain>
                                        <logger message="Getting Token: #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Getting Token"/>
                                    </processor-chain>
                                </when>
                                                        <otherwise>
                                                            <processor-chain>
                                                                            <!-- <logger message="401 Access Denied: Invalid Account Information" level="INFO" doc:name="401 Access Denied"/> -->
                                                                                <set-payload value="401 Access Denied: Invalid Account Information" doc:name="401 Access Denied" />
                                                                            <http:response-builder status="401" doc:name="HTTP 401" contentType="text/plain"/>
                                                                </processor-chain>
                                                        </otherwise>
                            </choice>
                        </processor-chain>
                    </when>
                                <otherwise>
                                    <processor-chain>
                                        <flow-ref name="405MethodNotAllowed" doc:name="405 Method Not Allowed"/>
                                    </processor-chain>
                                </otherwise>
                </choice>
            </processor-chain>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <processor-chain>
                <flow-ref name="404NotFound" doc:name="404 Not Found"/>
            </processor-chain>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
</sub-flow>

<sub-flow name="SOAP" doc:name="SOAP">
    <!-- <logger message="Launching SOAP Flow: #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Launching SOAP Flow"/> -->
            <choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when evaluator="groovy" expression="message.getInboundProperty('http.request')==~'^/soap/BuildingPermitService/v1/BuildingPermit\\?.*'">
            <processor-chain>
                <choice doc:name="Choice">
                    <when evaluator="header" expression="INBOUND:http.method=GET">
                        <processor-chain>
                            <!-- <logger message="Accessing to ${bpe.host}:${bpe.port}#[header:INBOUND:http.request.path]?#[header:INBOUND:http.query.string]" level="INFO" doc:name="Accessing to URL"/> -->
                            <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://${bpe.host}:${bpe.port}#[header:INBOUND:http.request.path]?#[header:INBOUND:http.query.string]" method="GET" doc:name="SOAP Service" responseTransformer-refs="WSDLTransformer"/>
                        </processor-chain>
                    </when>
                                <otherwise>
                                    <processor-chain>
                                        <flow-ref name="405MethodNotAllowed" doc:name="405 Method Not Allowed"/>
                                        </processor-chain>
                                </otherwise>
                </choice>
            </processor-chain>
        </when>
        <when evaluator="groovy" expression="message.getInboundProperty('http.request')==~'^/soap/BuildingPermitService/v1/BuildingPermit$'">
            <processor-chain>
                <choice doc:name="Choice">
                    <when evaluator="header" expression="INBOUND:http.method=POST">
                        <processor-chain>
                            <component class="ca.mpac.soa.HttpRequestToAuthorization" doc:name="HttpRequest To Authorization"/>
                                        <choice doc:name="Choice">
                                            <when evaluator="header" expression="INVOCATION:authResult=true">
                                                <processor-chain>
                                                    <!--
                                                    <logger message="Accessing to ${bpe.host}:${bpe.port}#[header:INBOUND:http.request]" level="INFO" doc:name="Accessing to URL"/>
                                        <component class="ca.mpac.soa.SoapRequest" doc:name="SOAP Request"/>
                                                    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://${bpe.host}:${bpe.port}#[header:INBOUND:http.request]" doc:name="SOAP Service" >
                                                            <cxf:proxy-client payload="envelope" />
                                                            <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
                                                    </http:outbound-endpoint>
                                                    -->
                                                    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://${bpe.host}:${bpe.port}/soap/BuildingPermitService/v1/BuildingPermit" doc:name="SOAP Service" >
                                                            <cxf:proxy-client payload="envelope" />
                                                            <!-- <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/> -->
                                                    </http:outbound-endpoint>
                                                    <!-- <logger message="Discovered an Authorization Request" level="INFO" doc:name="Discovered an Authorization Request"/> -->
                                                </processor-chain>
                                            </when>
                                            <when evaluator="header" expression="INVOCATION:authResult=false">
                                                <processor-chain>
                                                                            <logger message="403 Authorization Failure" level="INFO" doc:name="403 Authorization Failure"/>
                                                                            <expression-component doc:name="403 AuthorizationFailure"><![CDATA[
                                                                                             message.payload = '<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'UTF-8\'?>'
                                                                                                             + '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'
                                                                                                             + '<soap:Body>'
                                                                                                             + '<soap:Fault>'
                                                                                                             + '<faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>'
                                                                                                             + '<faultstring>A security fault has occured</faultstring>'
                                                                                                             + '<detail>'
                                                                                                             + '<ns2:securityFault xmlns:ns3="http://services.mpac.ca/soap/security/v1.0/schema" xmlns:ns2="http://services.mpac.ca/soap/common/faulttypes/v1.0/schema" xmlns="http://services.mpac.ca/soap/buildingpermit/v1.0/schema">'
                                                                                                             + '<ns2:name>AuthorizationFailure</ns2:name>'
                                                                                                             + '<ns2:status>403</ns2:status>'
                                                                                                             + '<ns2:reason>Client is unauthorized to use this service | please contact your MPAC representative</ns2:reason>'
                                                                                                             + '</ns2:securityFault>'
                                                                                                             + '</detail>'
                                                                                                             + '</soap:Fault>'
                                                                                                             + '</soap:Body>'
                                                                                                             + '</soap:Envelope>';
                                                                                    ]]></expression-component>
                                                                            <http:response-builder status="403" doc:name="HTTP 403" contentType="text/xml"/>
                                                </processor-chain>
                                            </when>
                                            <when evaluator="header" expression="INVOCATION:authResult=401">
                                                <processor-chain>
                                                                            <logger message="401 Access Denied: Invalid Token" level="INFO" doc:name="401 Access Denied"/>
                                                                                <expression-component doc:name="401 Access Denied: AuthenticationFailed"><![CDATA[
                                                                                             message.payload = '<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'UTF-8\'?>'
                                                                                                             + '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'
                                                                                                             + '<soap:Body>'
                                                                                                             + '<soap:Fault>'
                                                                                                             + '<faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>'
                                                                                                             + '<faultstring>A security fault has occured</faultstring>'
                                                                                                             + '<detail>'
                                                                                                             + '<ns2:securityFault xmlns:ns3="http://services.mpac.ca/soap/security/v1.0/schema" xmlns:ns2="http://services.mpac.ca/soap/common/faulttypes/v1.0/schema" xmlns="http://services.mpac.ca/soap/buildingpermit/v1.0/schema">'
                                                                                                             + '<ns2:name>AuthenticationFailed</ns2:name>'
                                                                                                             + '<ns2:status>401</ns2:status>'
                                                                                                             + '<ns2:reason>Client authentication has failed | please contact your MPAC representative</ns2:reason>'
                                                                                                             + '</ns2:securityFault>'
                                                                                                             + '</detail>'
                                                                                                             + '</soap:Fault>'
                                                                                                             + '</soap:Body>'
                                                                                                             + '</soap:Envelope>';
                                                                                    ]]></expression-component>
                                                                            <http:response-builder status="401" doc:name="HTTP 401" contentType="text/xml"/>
                                                </processor-chain>
                                            </when>
                                                        <otherwise>
                                                            <processor-chain>
                                                                            <component class="ca.mpac.soa.SoapActionErrorLog" doc:name="SoapActionErrorLog"/>
                                                                            <http:response-builder status="400" doc:name="HTTP 400" contentType="text/plain"/>
                                                                </processor-chain>
                                                        </otherwise>
                                        </choice>
                        </processor-chain>
                    </when>
                                <otherwise>
                                    <processor-chain>
                                        <flow-ref name="405MethodNotAllowed" doc:name="405 Method Not Allowed"/>
                                        </processor-chain>
                                </otherwise>
                </choice>
            </processor-chain>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <processor-chain>
                <flow-ref name="404NotFound" doc:name="404 Not Found"/>
                </processor-chain>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
</sub-flow>

<sub-flow name="404NotFound" doc:name="404NotFound">
    <logger message="404 Not Found: #[header:INBOUND:http.request]" level="INFO" doc:name="404 Not Found"/>
    <set-payload value="404 Not Found" doc:name="404 Not Found" />
    <http:response-builder status="404" doc:name="HTTP 404" contentType="text/plain"/>
</sub-flow>

<sub-flow name="405MethodNotAllowed" doc:name="405MethodNotAllowed">
    <logger message="405 Method Not Allowed: #[header:INBOUND:http.method]" level="INFO" doc:name="405 Method Not Allowed"/>
    <set-payload value="405 Method Not Allowed" doc:name="405 Method Not Allowed" />
    <http:response-builder status="405" doc:name="HTTP 405" contentType="text/plain"/>
</sub-flow>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known issue](http://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-6183) affecting Mule 3.3.0 and 3.3.1

It has been addressed and the fix will be part of the upcoming 3.4.0 release

Comment: I just tried Mule 3.4.0 and it is still the same.CPU spiking again.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having similar problems.